# Is it a subpanel?

Tags: wiring

I am putting in a new one hundred amp load center.  I have a present on/off main panel mounted next to the new load center.  My question:  Is the new load center now considered to be a sub panel?  If it is considered a sub panel, then will the neutral need to be isolated with a separate ground bus?

Comment: Is the neutral wire bonded anywhere in the on/off main panel, or does it just pass through?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Looks like an answer.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils -- make that an answer and I'll upvote

Answer (score 2):

If the on/off panel was done correctly, and it probably was, it has a main bonding jumper installed. I can't see any reason why you'd want to change that. So, yes; it's a sub-panel and the gounded/ing conductors should not be bonded together in the new one. If you want to verify it you'll have to remove the cover on the present panel.